# Magento Ajax cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

How to get cart qty without reload the page. I am using ajax cart module if i add to cart product add into cart but qty not increment if i reload the page only it increment

**minicart.phtml**

```
<?php
    $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount();
    if(empty($_cartQty)) {
        $_cartQty = 0;
   }
?>
<div class="bucket-wrap">
  <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl(); ?>" data-target-element="#header-cart" class="buket_icon skip-link skip-cart <?php if($_cartQty <= 0): ?> no-count<?php endif; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/bucket.png') ?>"/>
      <span><?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty(); ?></span></a>
</div>
<span class="arrow-icon hidden"></span>
<div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content hidden">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_content');?>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
//reload my cart
    public function cartAction()
    {   
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl(), '/', $this->_getRefererUrl());
        $myCart = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar', 'cart_sidebar')
                             ->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($myCart->toHtml());
    }

   //reload top cart
    public function mcartAction()
    {
        $template = Mage::getStoreConfig('amcart/reloading/path');
        if(!$template){
            $template = "checkout/cart/mini.phtml";
        }
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl(), '/', $this->_getRefererUrl());
        $myCart = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar', 'cart_sidebar')
                             ->setTemplate($template);
        $myCart->addItemRender('grouped', 'checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped', 'checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml');
        $myCart->addItemRender('configurable', 'checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable', 'checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml');

        $html = $myCart->toHtml();
        if($html == ""){
            $myCart->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar_header.phtml');
            $html = $myCart->toHtml();
        }
        if($html == ""){
            $this->loadLayout('default');         
            $block = Mage::app()->getLayout('default')->getBlock('minicart_head');
            if(is_object($block))
                $html = $block->toHtml();
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($html);

    }

     //reload shoppingcart
    public function checkoutAction()
    {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl(), '/', $this->_getRefererUrl());
        $this->loadLayout(array('checkout_cart_index')); 
        $myCart = Mage::app()->getLayout('checkout_cart_index')->getBlock('checkout.cart');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($myCart->toHtml());
    }

    //reload minicart
    public function minicartAction()
    {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl(), '/', $this->_getRefererUrl());
        $myCart = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar', 'cart_sidebar')
                             ->setTemplate('amasty/amcart/checkout/cart/mini_cart.phtml');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($myCart->toHtml());
    }
    //reload count
        public function dataAction()
        {
            $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('amcart/config', 'amcart.config');
            if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty() == 1){
                 $html = $this->__('There is') .' <a href="'.$block->getUrl('checkout/cart').'" id="am-a-count">1' . $this->__(' item') . '</a> '.$this->__('in your cart.');    
            }
            else{
                 $html = $this->__('There are') .' <a href="'.$block->getUrl('checkout/cart').'" id="am-a-count">'.Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty().  $this->__(' items') . '</a> '.  $this->__('in your cart.');    
            }
            $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
            $priceHtml = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal($cart));
            if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax($cart)){
                    $priceHtml .= '<br />(' . Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) .' ' . Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true). ')';
            }
            $result = array(
                'count' => $html,
                'price' => $priceHtml
            );
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));
        }

        //creating finale popup 
        private function addToCartResponse($product, $cart, $IsProductView, $params, $text){
           $result = array(
                      'title'     =>  $this->__('Information'), 
                      'message'   =>  '<p>' . $this->__('You have added product to cart.') . '</p>', 
                      'b1_name'   =>  $this->__('View cart'), 
                      'b2_name'   =>  $this->__('Continue'), 
                      'count'     =>  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty()>1?' (' . Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty(). $this->__(' items)'):' (' . Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty(). $this->__(' item)'),
                      'b1_action' =>  'document.location = "'.Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl().'";', 
                      'b2_action' =>  'jQuery.confirm.hide();',
                      'is_add_to_cart' =>  '1'
            );
```

**Problem is min cart is not reloading**

Comment: In which Action you have a hit for AddToCart?

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: which action you have hit for Ajax Cart?

Comment: Sorry i am new from this i thnink mcartAction()

Answer (score 0):

As per as,your comment,`AddtoCart` is execute from *`mcartAction`*.

I have seen that your tried to return some block `'minicart_head','checkout/cart_sidebar'` etc from that Action using `$this->getResponse()->setBody($html);`

I assume that your **`minicart`** section `<div id="header-cart"` has been updated properly and you have issue with **`class="bucket-wrap"`** section qty update.

If you will `return Current Cart qty` from **mcartAction** then it will work perfectly.

```
$result[html]=$html;
  $result[qty]=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty();;
  $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
  $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

Note: I have return JSON at here.So need to change something at Ajax success method